Does Hermann Gunkel’s pioneering form-critical work on the psalms encroach on inspiration?
Hans-Joachim Kraus’s monumental work on the Psalms often refers to Hermann Gunkel’s commentary on the Psalms. In his commentary on Psalm 28,2, Kraus writes the following: “H. Gunkel suggests that we supply הביטה: ‘Look up when I lift up my hands. . . . !’” (Hans-Joachim Kraus, Psalm 1-59 (Minneapolis, MN: Crossway, 1993), p. 339). This is suggested to ‘force fit’ a certain meter for verse 2 (“two five-pulse meters”). I couldn’t find a reference anywhere regarding the inclusion of the verb ‘נבט’ (look, consider: (Hiphil)), and the Massoretic Text does not indicate any such variant reading:

Basically, I’m looking for any reference of Gunkel’s to his suggested modification to this particular verse in Psalm 28. I believe there are also others examples.

Can you please explain in more detail how form criticism could encroach on inspiration? And that question from the title doesn't seem related at all to what is in the question body.

Dear Curious, I wasn't even aware of form-criticism until I stumbled across it going through Kraus's work and I was not familiar with Gunkel. We didn't cover that in seminary back in the 70's. It seems that Dan Fefferman's response below would more address your concern which is no doubt valid seeing that I am not the best one to comment on form-critical works and what conservatives label as inspiration. Mike Sangrey suggested I move the question to the Christianity Stack Exchange site. Sorry for any confusion. I was simply curious about any relation between these two areas of study.

Well it's still your question, so you should be able to explain why you think form criticism would encroach on inspiration. We want questions to stand on their own merits here, not to need answers to provide justification for the questions, if that makes sense. Form criticism is just an approach that looks at forms and hypothesises about oral sources, neither of which have any direct relevance to the inspiration of scripture.

That does make sense and I'm wondering if the question could have been worded differently to avoid any confusion or if, like you wrote, there's no connection whatsoever between the two disciplines.

Gunkel was indeed a pioneer of form-criticism applied to the psalms. For those who reject historical-criticism of the Bible out of hand, the answer is clearly yes - it does does encroach on inspiration. But in Gunkel's case, he tried to reach the original spirituality of the psalms, rather than merely provide a literal translation. In this case, he understands the psalmist to express a sense of pleading with God with his whole body - eyes as well as hands - rather than only raising one's hands.
Like the OP, I cannot find a reference to Gunkel's explanation about his translation. But it's apparent from other cases that he was willing to significantly alter the text. For example, according to this article Gunkel once rendered Psalm 42:4 in this fashion:

I went to the tabernacle and danced my way to the house of Yahweh
with shouts of joy and thanksgiving amid the high-spirited tumult.

YLT reads:

I pass over into the booth, I go softly with them unto the house of
God, With the voice of singing and confession, The multitude keeping
feast!

NIV reads

I used to go to the house of God under the protection of the Mighty
One with shouts of joy and praise among the festive throng.

Here Gunkel chose to render the verse so as to portray David dancing as in 2 Samuel 6:5, while other translators handled the verse in different ways. David's dancing is not in the original text, but it may be understood as implied, so this is an attempt at an authentic - if not literal - interpretation of the poetry.
Conclusion: Gunkel sometimes plays "fast and loose" with the text for poetic purposes. A "force-fit" to an appropriate meter may or may not be the case here. However, elsewhere he apparently changed the literal translation to better express what he believes the poet to be saying. Whether this encroaches on inspiration is a matter of opinion.
